# Using quote as background image IE issue

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, background-image

I am pretty sure that using `line-height` is not the best option here but it works for Chrome, Firefox -  IE seems to have issues with alignment.

Any hint? What I should should try here -  [jsfiddle.net/9AZyr/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/9AZyr/1/)

Thank you!

Comment: I like the way how it is aligned bottom(to text) on chrome. 

Not so happy with IE when its not aligned bottom and line-height is an issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I floated the pseudo elements. The closing quote is to the right, away from the period. But here was my though, you can't predict where the end of the sentence is on any 1 screen. Instead forcing it to the far right sort of lines things up more consistently. It also causes the text to flow around the closing image.

http://jsfiddle.net/9AZyr/3/

```
.quotetestimonial3:after {
content: url('http://dhrumin.com/uploads/glyph-white2.png');
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top:-1em;
vertical-align: text-top;
line-height: 250%;
clear:both;
float:right;
```

}

Comment: I understand that but this is something static html page I am working on and need to copy design style :(

Comment: why cant you add float:left; and float:right; to your CSS?

Comment: Actually you are correct - Its working here [link]http://jsfiddle.net/9AZyr/4/

Thank you!!